# Symfony 2.6 overrides PHPUnit_Framework_Error

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, symfony-2.6

I have a unit tested application which we have updated from symfony 2.3 to 2.6. We followed all upgrading docs and had to change only some minor stuff.
Everything is working perfectly, except for the PHPUnit tests.

We have 2 seperate runs, one for only testing the entity classes, which is fired on a pre-commit hook. and a second one which runs the full suite, with database setups and the whole nine yards.

Now since the upgrade to 2.6, the `PHPUnit_Framework_Error` thrown in the unit tests have been replaced by Symfony's `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException`, this failing all tests like this:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider objectTestDataProvider
 * @expectedException \PHPUnit_Framework_Error
 */
public function testCanNotSetClientToArbitraryValue($value)
```

Now I do not want to change this into the new Exception since running the entity-only test suite does not depend on symfony components, thus symfony is not loaded, thus the errors are the regular `PHPUnit_Framework_Error` so changing it makes these tests fail.

In other words, when I run one test class it works, once a symfony dependent test is run, it fails:

```
# runs perfectly
phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml --debug src/My/Bundle/Tests/Entity
# fails when reaching the tests that ran perfectly in previous command
phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml --debug
```

This new ErrorHandler seems undocumented, I couldnt find much about it in google except for the pull request and [this small article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/debug/introduction.html)

I've tried:

- setting the `SYMFONY_DEBUG=0` environment variable, but this doesnt seem to make any difference.
- adding the `debug.error_handler.throw_at: 0` parameter to my test_config.yml

**edit:**

On request by @cerad I've tried to isolate the tests to try and reproduce the code with as little  as possible, Ive managed to reproduce with 4 tests:

```
class MyControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testRoutesLoaded_1()
    {
        $client = self::createClient();

        /** @var Router $router */
        $router = $client->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('router');
        $this->assertEquals('/menu', $router->generate('front_menu'));
    }

    /**
     * @expectedException \PHPUnit_Framework_Error
     */
    public function testCreateOrder_1()
    {
        new Order(); // required parameter missing
    }

    public function testRoutesLoaded_2()
    {
        $client = $this->createNewFrontClient();

        /** @var Router $router */
        $router = $client->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('router');
        $this->assertEquals('/menu', $router->generate('front_menu'));
    }

    /**
     * @expectedException \PHPUnit_Framework_Error
     */
    public function testCreateOrder_2()
    {
        new Order(); // required parameter missing
    }
}
```

As you can see, I just run the same exact test 2 times, but still the last one results in an error:

> MyControllerTest::testCreateOrder_2
>   Failed asserting that exception of type "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException" matches expected exception "\PHPUnit_Framework_Error"

Comment: Is it possible to isolate this behavior to one reasonably small unit test?

Comment: yes, I have 1 test that loads symfony, and checks if a route exists, and a second test that throws an error. The second test fails if the first one was executed first, overriding the PHPUnit error handler

Comment: Ok.  I don't understand the part about the second test failing if the first one was executed first.  In any event, could you post some code?  I can't claim to have extensive tests but those that I do have, survived the 2.3 to 2.5 upgrade just fine.  And just to clarify, we are talking about 2.5.6?  Or are you using 2.6.0-dev?

Comment: we use 2.6.* in composer. I have tried to isolate it in simple tests, but it works as expected, so I guess its going wrong elsewhere...

Comment: I've got a testcase to reproduce this, with only 4 tests, see updated question.

Comment: `ContextErrorException` is usually thrown from Symfony2's error handler function, check where it is registered, maybe there is a bug which still registers it even with debug switched off.

Comment: yes it is called from Symfony's error handeler, [registered here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/FrameworkBundle.php#L50) in both the 1st and 3rd test, but the second passes, and the fourth fails... while exactly the same happens both times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I did not get any replies here, I posted an [issue on Symfony's github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12327) and they confirmed this was incorrect behavior.

The issue was resolved and is [merged in 2.6-dev](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/0588f0e8fb3da36efa2e723e836a87f206a6e436).

Comment: I have a notice, that if you have faced this issue and updated Symfony, you'll have to manually clear cache (```rm -rf app/cache/*```) in order to get application working. It's because incorrect behaviour is cached and ```cache:clear``` reads cache first.